# how to make tabular width stretch to page

Tags: tables

How ? my code and result below

```
\chapter*{Camera Calibration Data, \\ Cont'd}

Focal Length in x = 953.58\\
Focal Length in y = 953.58\\
Principal Point = (959.5, 539.5)\\


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
Camera 1 & $\begin{array}{ccc} 0.99997 & -0.00769 & 0.00016 \\ -0.00500 & -0.66628 &-0.74569 \\ 0.00585 & 0.74567 & -0.66630 \end{array}$ & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &   0& 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &  0 & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &0  & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &  0 & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &  0 & 0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I am trying to make it look like
[image]

Comment: Please don't add your code as a screenshot, but as a codeblock. This makes it big enough to actually read and we can simply copy it. And please clarify what your intended output should look like.

Comment: I would not make the effort to use `array`, simply put the numbers directly into the tabular: http://pastebin.com/443JajUY

Comment: Aren't all your numbers missing their unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you posted is not made by `tabular` from the code you posted but probably a misused? `tabular*`. You can use `tabular*` as below but as you see, the effect of stretching the table is just to make it harder to read.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Camera Calibration Data, \\ Cont'd}

Focal Length in x = 953.58\\
Focal Length in y = 953.58\\
Principal Point = (959.5, 539.5)%no!\\

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
Camera 1 & $\begin{array}{ccc} 0.99997 & -0.00769 & 0.00016 \\ -0.00500 & -0.66628 &-0.74569 \\ 0.00585 & 0.74567 & -0.66630 \end{array}$ & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &   0& 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &  0 & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &0  & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &  0 & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &  0 & 0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|@{}}
  \hline
Camera 1 & $\begin{array}{ccc} 0.99997 & -0.00769 & 0.00016 \\ -0.00500 & -0.66628 &-0.74569 \\ 0.00585 & 0.74567 & -0.66630 \end{array}$ & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &   0& 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &  0 & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &0  & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &  0 & 0\\
\hline
Camera 2 &  0 & 0\\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks ! do you know how I can make all the entries center ? I am just trying to learn latex by redoing my old report (attached new image) This is by far tougher than any programming language I have ever learnt. I thought the argument |c|c|c| would make all the entries center

Comment: @kong `c` does make them center and I would use `tabular` as in the first table above. `tabular*` adds extra intercolumn space but only on one side of the | so if using that do not use vertical rules (not using vertical rules is a good idea anyway)

Answer (score 3):

Just FYI, a table version

- without vertical lines, and
- with less horizontal lines including better vertical spacing by the rules of package `booktabs`.
- As David Carlisle pointed out, for better readability, the table is not horizontally stretched.
- The numbers are aligned at the decimal dot (except the number in exponential format). Package `siunitx` is used with table column type `S`.
- The camera settings are separated by a little vertical space (`\addlinespace` of package `booktabs`).

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{
    l
    *{3}{S[table-format=-1.5]}
    S[table-format=-2.2] % minus sign is larger than the leading 1
  }
    \toprule
    &&&& {Camera Position} \\
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Rotation Matrix}
    & {$[x\;y\;z]^{\mathrm{T}}$}\\
    \midrule
    Camera 1 &  0.99997 & -0.00769 &  0.00016 &  87.56 \\
             & -0.00500 & -0.66628 & -0.74569 & -34.52 \\
             &  0.00585 &  0.74567 & -0.66630 &  60.69 \\
    \addlinespace
    Camera 2 & -0.99998 & {7.600e-5}&  0.00628 &  87.69 \\
             & -0.00475 &  0.66371 & -0.74797 & 103.14 \\
             &  0.00065 &  0.76363 & -0.64565 &  60.62 \\
    \addlinespace
    Camera 3 &  0.99997 & -0.00564 & -0.00567 &  53.15 \\
             & -0.00797 & -0.64563 & -0.76361 & -34.13 \\
             &  0.00065 &  0.76363 & -0.64565 &  56.51 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `array` just makes this unnecessarily complicate. I would simply place the numbers directly in the tabular.

To get the numbers aligned with respect to their decimal markers, I added `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Focal Length in x = 953.58

Focal Length in y = 953.58

Principal Point = (959.5, 539.5)

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
    @{}|X|SSS|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|@{}}
  \hline
                & 0.99997 & -0.00769 & 0.00016 & \\
    Camera 1    & -0.00500 & -0.66628 &-0.74569 & 0\\
                & 0.00585 & 0.74567 & -0.66630 & \\
    \hline
                & 0.99997 & -0.00769 & 0.00016 & \\
    Camera 1    & -0.00500 & -0.66628 &-0.74569 & 0\\
                & 0.00585 & 0.74567 & -0.66630 & \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Off-topic, but perhaps you are interested in reading https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

Comment: also see https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/

Comment: @Zarko Nice link!